# Trouble understanding reference types / reference copying in Service Locator implementation

Tags: c#, reference, service-locator

In implementing a Service Locator, I've come across something I'm confused about with regards to reference types.

In the code below, I have a static class `ServiceLocator` which exposes 2 static methods, `GetService` and `ProvideService` - get returns the current service, and provide takes a new service as an argument and assigns it to the current service variable. If the provided service is null, it assigns `currentService` to a static `defaultService` initialised at the start of the class declaration. Simple stuff:

```
public static class ServiceLocator {
    private static readonly Service defaultService = new Service();
    private static Service currentService = defaultService;

    public static Service GetService() {
        return currentService;
    }

    public static void ProvideService(Service service) {
        currentService = service ?? defaultService;
    }
}
```

What i'm confused about is this: I have a separate class which stores a reference to the `currentService` at the start of *its* class declaration in the variable named `referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart`. When I provide the service locator with a new Service instance to update the current service, `referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart` appears instead to maintain the reference to `defaultService`:

```
public class ClassThatUsesService {
    private Service referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart = ServiceLocator.GetService();

    private static ClassThatUsesService() {
        ServiceLocator.ProvideService(new Service());
        // this variable appears to still reference the defaultService 
        referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart != ServiceLocator.GetService()
    }
}
```

So the references appear to follow this kind of chain:

```
referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart -> defaultService -> (Service in memory)
```

Which is understandable, since `referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart` simply copies the `currentService` reference. *However, the behaviour I'm looking for/would like is for `referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart` to always reference whatever `currentService` references, so it's updated by `Provide()`. Something more akin to:*

```
referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart -> currentService -> (Service> in memory)
```

So, is this behaviour possible? I'm really unsure of how I'd achieve this kind of reference behaviour. I'm new to C# so it's very possible there's some obvious language feature I'm clueless about. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this behaviour possible?

No, not as you've described it. As you're already aware, all you get is a copy of the original reference. Changing the original reference doesn't change the copy, any more than copying the value of an `int` variable to another would allow you to later change the original and have the copy change:

```
int original = 17;
int copy = original;

original = 19;
// "copy" is still 17, of course!
```

If you want to always have the current value of the reference in `ServiceLocator`, then you should just always retrieve the value from that class, rather than using a local field. In your above example, you might indirect through a property, e.g.:

```
public class ClassThatUsesService {
    private Service referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart => ServiceLocator.GetService();
}
```

It's a one character change (the `=` becomes `=>`), but don't be fooled. It's a *significant* change in implementation. What you wind up with instead of a field, is a read-only property (i.e. has only a `get` method and no `set` method), where that property's `get` method calls the `ServiceLocator.GetService()` method and returns the result.

Personally, I wouldn't bother. Unless you have some very strong expectation that the implementation of `referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart` will change in the future, you should just call `ServiceLocator.GetService()` directly. Don't even have the `referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart` property. Since the code expects to always get the current value, the best way to ensure that is to just *always get the current value*, straight from the class where that value is stored.

Finally, I'll take the opportunity to show a scenario that is similar to what you're asking, but not exactly. In particular, because you're trying to store the reference in a class field, the above is how you need to do it. But, the latest C# has ["reference return values"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#reference-return-values), which must be stored in ["ref locals"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals). Since you want to reference a `static` field, which is guaranteed to always exist, you can in fact return a reference *to the field*, store that in a local, and when you retrieve the local variable's value, it will always have whatever is in the field, because it's a reference to the field, not a copy of it.

You can see the example in the documentation (see links above), but here's another example that is more similar to what you're doing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // stores a reference to the value returned by M1(), which is to say,
        // a reference to the B._o field.
        ref A a1 = ref B.M1();

        // Keep the original value, and create a new A instance
        A original = a1, a2 = new A();

        // Update the B._o field to the new A instance
        B.M2(a2);

        // Check the current state
        Console.WriteLine($"original.ID: {original.ID}");
        Console.WriteLine($"a1.ID: {a1.ID}");
        Console.WriteLine($"a2.ID: {a2.ID}");
    }
}

class A
{
    private static int _id;

    public int ID { get; }

    public A()
    {
        ID = ++_id;
    }
}

class B
{
    private static A _o = new A();

    public static ref A M1()
    {
        // returns a _reference_ to the _o field, rather than a copy of its value
        return ref _o;
    }

    public static void M2(A o)
    {
        _o = o;
    }
}
```

When you run the above, you'll get this output:

```
original.ID: 1
a1.ID: 2
a2.ID: 2
```

In other words, the variable `a1` winds up yielding the same value found in `a2`, which is the new object passed to the `B.M2()` method to modify the `B._o` field, while the original copy of the `B._o` field value remains a reference to the original object that field referenced.

This doesn't work in your case, because the `ref` value that's returned has to be stored in a `ref` local. You can't put it into a class field. But it's similar enough to your scenario that I wanted to mention it, in case you want to change your design to allow that, or want to use that technique in some other scenario that does work in that way.

Comment: Great answer, thank's very much. Unfortunately I'm using Unity which doesn't have the c#7 ref features, but I'm glad to have learnt something new!

Comment: Ah. In Unity, you might also not have the `=>` lambda property syntax either. That's a lot easier to work around, just implement explicitly: `private Service referenceToCurrentServiceAtStart { get { return ServiceLocator.GetService(); } }`. But, I do still recommend not having the property and just calling `GetService()` where you need that value.